# Android Java set the height to a fraction of width

Tags: java, android, aspect-ratio

Developing an app in **Android Studio**
I have the width of my `ImageView` set to "match_parent".
I am trying to set the height of it to "the width / 3".  In other words I am trying to maintain an aspect ratio of 3:1 regardless of the screen size of the device it runs on. 
I know I can't do it in XML because you can only set values to literal values.
At runtime I can use this statement.

```
img.getLayoutParams().height = img.getWidth() / 3;
```

and that will work but if I put that in the `onCreate` or the onStart methods `getWidth` returns 0 because the view hasn't been created yet.  There's got to be a place I can place this code so that it simply runs after the `Activity` starts.

I tried this:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    float RATIO = 1/3;
    setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams((int)RATIO * w, w));
}
```

But the `onSizeChanged` and `setLayoutParams` are turned red and I don't know where I need to put this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DisplayMetrics` like below

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        height = metrics.heightPixels;
        width = metrics.widthPixels;
       int homePageButtonPanelHeight = height / 7;

       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            homePageButtonPanelHeight - 5, homePageButtonPanelHeight - 5);
       LinearLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            homePageButtonPanelHeight, homePageButtonPanelHeight + 30);

      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams paramIcon = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            homePageButtonPanelHeight - 5, homePageButtonPanelHeight - 5);


      icon.setLayoutParams(paramIcon);

      btn1.setLayoutParams(params2);

      btn2.setLayoutParams(params2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, width/3));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions to both of you.
Prabhuraj I can have the height set no problem with the line

     img.getLayoutParams().height = img.getWidth() / 3;

but the problem was in putting that line in a place where it will execute when the activity is finished loading.  But I will try the "metrics" solution suggested by anusha tomorrow and I'll post back.

Thanks again!